# Script or launcher to setup multiple terminal tabs in different locations

Tags: linux, linux-terminal

I have already studied this some time ago, but did not find any solution that would open terminal tabs, run some commands and then allow me to continue using those terminal tabs. All the ways I found launching terminal tabs from command line would only launch the tabs and not allow me to continue using them after that.

The problem I am trying to solve is that every time I need to boot my machine (or virtual machine in this case) I need to setup around six different terminal tabs to point to different folders and to export some environment variables on some of them.

I have experimented with xfce terminal and I have gotten some way with command like this:

```
terminal --disable-server -H --tab --title=1st_tab --tab --title=2nd_tab
```

But if I add command argument, the tab is not usable anymore when it opens:

```
terminal --disable-server -H --tab --title=1st_tab --tab --title=2nd_tab --command="cd ~/folder1"
```

http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/command-line

I am currently using Red Hat Linux with gnome 2.28.2.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this using [`GNOME terminator`](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) which is a great terminal with, among other things, the ability to split panes horizontally or vertically.

Once you have installed `terminator` you can set up a profile with your desired settings (instructions adapted from [here](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html)):

1. Run `terminator`, and set up the layout you want. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to split windows vertically and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's O as in oodles, not zero) to split horizontally. For this example, I have created a layout with 6 panes:

[image]

2. Right click on the `terminator` window and chose "Preferences". Once the Preferences window is open, go to "Layouts" and click "Add":

[image]

3. That will populate the Layout list with your new layout:

[image]

4. Find each of the terminals you have created in the layout, and click on them, then on the right enter the command you want to run in them on startup:

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** Note that the command is followed by `; bash`. If you don't do that the terminals will not be accessible since they will run the command you give and exit. You need to launch a shell after each command to be able to use the terminals.

Once you have set all the commands click "Close" and then exit `terminator`.

4. Open the `terminator` config file `~/.config/terminator/config` and delete the section under layouts for the default config. Then change the name of the layout you created to default. It should look something like this:

   ```
    [global_config]
    [keybindings]
    [profiles]
      [[default]]
    [layouts]
      [[default]]
        [[[child0]]]
          position = 446:100
          type = Window
          order = 0
          parent = ""
          size = 885, 550
        [[[child1]]]
          position = 444
          type = HPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child0
        [[[child2]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child1
        [[[child5]]]
          position = 219
          type = HPaned
          order = 1
          parent = child1
        [[[child6]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child5
        [[[child9]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 1
          parent = child5
        [[[terminal11]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'df -h; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child9
        [[[terminal10]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'export foo="bar" && cd /var/www/; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child9
        [[[terminal3]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'ssh -Yp 24222 cchapple@139.124.66.43'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child2
        [[[terminal4]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'top; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child2
        [[[terminal7]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'cd /etc; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child6
        [[[terminal8]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'cd ~/dev; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child6
    [plugins]
   ```

The final result is that when you run `terminator` it will open with 6 panes, each of which has run or is running the commands you have specified:

[image]

Comment: After I enter my commands in `Custom command` box, and hit close,  it is not saved when re-opened. May I know why? I'm using Ubuntu 16 Desktop

Comment: @NamGVU hmm, I just tested and I have the same problem. Looks like a bug in the current version of terminator (this worked 3 years ago when this answer was posted). It still works if you edit the `~/.config/terminator/config` file as shown in step 5.

Comment: In a recent version of `terminator` (mine is 2.0.1) there is no need for the `command`: one can just specify the `working directory` right below that field.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for including also snippets.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have Terminator `cd` into a directory on launch, the command to configure is:

```
cd ~/someFolder; bash
```

This opens a terminal in the location `cd`ed to.

Actually, terdon does mention this in his post but it is buried in his wonderful mini-tutorial. It wasn't after I'd figured this out that I noticed it buried in his post, so I'm leaving this answer in order to emphasize.

Answer (score 0):

The command must be followed by `"; bash"`. Rest should be as per terdon's answers https://superuser.com/a/610048