# Keep Session with Terminator

Tags: terminal, session, linux-terminal, terminator

I am using Terminator for multiple Terminal Sessions. I know I can start with custom Session layout but most of the time I have changing Session settings.

Is it possible to save the current Session with terminator? For example if I shutdown the PC and then restore my old session on next start-up.

Comment: For those who can save a session manually, here is the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/610001/script-or-launcher-to-setup-multiple-terminal-tabs-in-different-locations/610048#610048

Answer (score 1):

Your tags are for Linux so I assume you are not using this Java based emulator from windows, right?

Linux, Unix, OSX... use Screen or TMUX terminal Multiplexers both available in nearly all repos.

[Screen Command – Beginners Guide to Terminal Multiplexing](https://www.putorius.net/linux-screen-command.html)

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: @Toto: My anser is not "Link Only" and I feel that my answer is quite self explanatory in that there are native solutions that allow detaching and reattaching that are explained very well with examples in the linked blog post.

***From the top of that article:***
"The Linux Screen utility allows you to run several login sessions inside a single terminal display. There are many benefits to using screen like the ability to detach and reattach sessions, and allowing remote processes to continue after you have disconnected from a system. This is known as terminal multiplexing."

Comment: @rjbradlow Your solution does not work across reboots, which is exactly what OP asks. So it is indeed mostly just a link, that does not help.