# bash terminal that remembers its state when restored from a crash

Tags: bash, terminal, session-restore

In Ubuntu, I use the default `gnome-terminal` to run my commands. I typically have a couple of windows open, each with several tabs. When my OS crashes∗, for whatever reason, and I reboot,  I lose all these terminals.

Sublime Text, Firefox and Chrome have spoilt me, as all of them give me the option to restore all the windows and tabs to exactly what they were doing prior to the crash, and I would like to be able to do the same with my terminal windows and tabs.

How can this be accomplished?

Spelling out the specifics of what I would like:

- Must have:

  - Upon reboot, when I open terminal for the first time, the windows and tabs that were there before get re-opened

    - Either with or without a prompt is fine
  - Each tab is `cd`-ed into the folder that it was in before
- Nice to have:

  - The `bash_history` for that tab is still there
  - so when I press the "up" and "down" keys, I would get what I expect within that tab

---

∗ Ubuntu running on a laptop whose drivers are not the most friendly, happens more often than I would like (in case you are wondering)

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something [like this](http://superuser.com/q/610001/151431)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest they could get was.

You can use the following options:

```
--save-config=FILE              Save the terminal configuration to a file
--load-config=FILE              Load a terminal configuration file
```

Example:

To save:

```
gnome-terminal --save-config=/tmp/cfgtab
```

To load it back:

```
gnome-terminal --load-config=/tmp/cfgtab
```

[image]

Comment: @tiagoc Hmm - does this work globally - i.e. if I execute this command from any shell/ terminal, it will save the context from every currently open one? ... 'Cos if so, what I'm thinking is I could set up a `cron` job, or even just a simple `watch -n5 gnome-terminal --save-config=/tmp/cfgtab` and upon a crash I can simply reload the sessions by running `gnome-terminal --load-config=/tmp/cfgtab` manually.

Comment: @bguiz Yes, at least the current working directory of each tab is saved. As the typed commands, everything is saved to `bash_history`. While remembering the commands in a tab in particular I think it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the new `gnome-terminal` in Gnome 3 has dropped support for loading and saving configs :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

https://gist.github.com/bguiz/9262902

It is a shell script that automates the above.

For normal use:

```
~/watcher.sh
```

After a crash and reboot:

```
~/watcher.sh restore
```

Comment: @tiagoc I have come up with my solution inspired by yours. I'll give you a +1 and check, since you led me to the solution - thanks!

Comment: @tiagoc would you share the solution you came up with?